# Regression on longitudinal data with varying observations times

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, panel-data

I have a question about performing regression for prediction on a continuous dependent variable that is time dependent. The table below shows an hypothetical structure of my data.

[image]

I want to estimate the response variable at any time period 1 to 6 weeks, using covariates such as shown in the example below, with response time being one of my predictor variables.

As shown in the example data, the data available for different patients differ. So if I convert my data to a long format, with response time as a predictor, then the data for patient C will appear 7 times while the data for patient B will appear only two times.

What is the proper way to use and model data in this situation? (a) should I adjust data so each patient appears an equal number of times or can I use the data as it is; (b) are there special modelling approaches to use or can I use General Linear Models?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what you expect from the responses.  Is there an upper/lower limit, then a logistic function might fit.  If there are no limits, a linear function might be a first trial.  Ideal would be if you had a physical theory behind the observations which would give you the most appropriate model function.

Comment: thanks for contributing. However, as stated in my question, I want to predict on a continuous response variable. Thus logistic regression is not applicable. Also, my question does not deal with basic modelling approaches, but specifically with how to legitimately handle data with the specific structure type shown in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why does everybody seem to think that logistic regression is only for 0/1 variables???  In fact, that is a misuse of regression.  See examples here:
https://www.lerenisplezant.be/teksten/FittingKVdm-Manual.pdf